# USB Type-C to Type-C Cable has voltage in one orientation only

Tags: usb, battery-charging, battery-operated, usb-c

I'm designing a battery powered device, which gets charged with 5V.
I wanted Type-C as the charging interface, so I designed an appropiate Type-C Port for the device:

[image]
As you can see, I added the needed 5.1k Pull Downs on CC1 and CC2, to get 5V.

Well, It works as it should when I charge via an USB-A to USB-C cable with my phone wall charger.
But when I use a modern Type-C charger with a Type-C to Type-C cable, it only gives voltage in one plug-orientation and I can't understand why. In the other orientation there is no voltage on VBUS (or anywhere).

I think I did everything needed to get standard 5V from Type-C. As I don't need special voltages or current, I don't want to add an overpriced PD-Controller.

I tested the same setup with a Type-C female breakout-board and it was the same.

Type-C Connector in schematic: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811101526_Korean-Hroparts-Elec-TYPE-C-31-M-16_C283541.pdf

Comment: If you say "in one plug-orientation" you mean the orientation on the charger side, I guess? In total there are 4 combinations of orientation on both ends combined.

Comment: I mean the plug that goes into my device. The charger side one can be flipped as I like, It doesn't change anything.

Comment: You could try connecting the other GND and VBUS pins as well.

Comment: Well, I connected all possible GND and VBUS pins of the Type-C connector, as you can see in the schematic. Which else do you mean?

Comment: The full spec USB-C connectors have four GND pins (A1,A12,B1,B12) and four VBUS pins (A4,A9,B4,B9)

Comment: Yeah, but I tought that all these SMD Type-C connectors like I used (see added datasheet link), have them connected internally. Unfortunately there is no more information about them. 

https://www.ebay.de/itm/183827222448 This is the breakout board I used additionally.

Comment: It would be really interesting to know if the charger is supposed to connect all four VBUS and GND connections, if the cable, the device or Type-C connectors are supposed to do so. It's at least obvious that this particular Type-C connector doesn't.

Comment: Just for sanity, did you try different cables?

Comment: yes, and two different power supplies. The one that came with my oculus quest and the other was the new USB-C 65W Power supply from Xiaomi. Each with their cables and tested both with my phone, where of course both orientations worked.

Comment: Can you connect a breakout on both sides of the cables and measure to see if there is any built in resistor

Comment: That's a good Idea, I will try it

Comment: Specifically look for resistance between cc pins and ground but also check resistance between each pin on both sides.